# Paging disparate items in a single list

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate

I struggle with posting questions like this here as I don't have a specific error I'm encountering so much as looking for help. While I do believe questions should be code related (pseudo-code even), I don't feel you have to have an error code before you can post for help on StackOverflow, so here goes.

I'm looking for a way to combine items from two disparate datasources to a single collection, and apply paging so that they appear in order of their creation. Existing logic doing each separate is very simple, and can be done via SQL directly or even in C# using Linq expressions (in my case NHibernate DAL would resolve it to SQL, but that's beyond my scope of the question I think)

My scenario is I have a comments concept and a documents/attachments concept in a business application. Both are currently separate, I'm looking to combine them in to a sort of "Journal" implementation where comments and documents are listed in the order they were added in a consolidated list, and just conditionally show display information for the comment or document depending on the item in the current enumeration while building up the UI.

The problem is the paging. Merging the top X from both datasources and then applying the same X limit works for page 1 (though a little wasteful), but completely falls apart on subsequent pages. I can't directly join both objects in my DAL abstraction because they are completely disparate types. I thought about using date ranges for the start and end of each page, instead of page index, but it seems pretty fragile conceptually. I thought about using raw SQL to get an combined query working across both tables, sort by DateCreated, and only return the ID's of the rows (guids) returned by paging, and then do a subsequent query for just the rows matching those Ids, but I'm not sure that's the best way either.

I'm looking for concepts or even pseudocode descriptions of things you may have some experience with or suggestions I can build on for something like this? Whether they rely on something at .NET level, NHibernate or SQL.

Comment: Why do you need to have those in one list if they are completely different types? It seems that there is the conceptual problem but it is much deeper than the one you've described.

Comment: It's meant to be similar to a timeline example that shows many disparate events in a single sequence. My problem is they are stored in different datasources so I'm trying to figure out how to get them into a single list within my code base for use within my view.

Comment: It also occurs to me this might be similar to an implementation of a Ajax scrolling element, where you have to list elements dynamically as needed, continuing on the paging of results from the end of the previous ajax request? I'm only guessing as I've not looked at implementation of endless scrolling yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fiddle with database why not implement something common to those types? My idea is to create another database table called 'JournalEntry' (Name is arbitrary) to which both of those items have a 1:1 connection. Those JournalEntries would have a backreference to their parent type (Documents or Attachments or other things):

```
JounrnalEntry {
  Int Id,
  DateTime DateCreated
  EnumEntryType (Doc / Attachment)
}
```

You can then

```
JournalEntries
.OrderBy(e => e.DateCreated)
.Skip(page * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)
.Select( ... )
```

The problem is once again in this Select (Since you can't store different types in one collection) - you'll probably add some common type or stick with this JournalEntry type in your code until you for sure need the detailed info about the item.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking I may need to look at as a longer term project as well. Merging the common elements to a sort of `Journal` table, and then using a 1:1 relationship to get a table-per-subtype approach. I was hoping to see if there was an option I'm overlooking for the short term

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Union all option as mentioned below, and handle the paging logic in C# code

Or

you can use the blow query and implement paging on top of this. May be you can use CTE for paging in SQL

```
select id, datecreated, recType, comments, document From (
Select id, datecreated, 'DOC' as recType, '' comments, document from table_one
union all
select id, datecreated, 'COM' as recType, comments, null as dcoument from table_two
) as joined_table
order by datecreated
```

Comment: I've thought about doing this as well. My only issue is that trying to cast the resulting objects to this custom object because of the dynamically composed rows, means I can't rely on any native control of cashing in my DAL, so I'm essentially doing it all manually. it ends up being very brittle.